# Whats wrong in following attempt to write Hermite polynomials in terms of hypergeometric function?

Tags: taylor-expansion, generating-functions, hypergeometric-function

Let's have Hermite polynomials:
$$
e^{2tx - t^{2}} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}H_{n}(x)\frac{t^{n}}{n!}. \qquad (1)
$$
I need to write it in terms of confluent hypergeometric Kummer function for index $n = 2k$. The result is
$$
H_{2k}(x) = (-1)^{k}\frac{(2k)!}{k!}F_{1}\left(-n, \frac{1}{2}, x^{2}\right).
$$
I tried to prove it by the following way. First, I expanded polynomials in Taylor series near zero:
$$
H_{n}(x) = \sum_{m}H^{(m)}_{n}(0)\frac{x^{n}}{n!}, \quad H_{n}^{(m)}(0) = \frac{dH_{n}}{dx} \quad at \quad  x = 0. \qquad (2)
$$
Then I used $(1)$:
$$
\partial_{x}^{m}G(x, t)_{x = 0} = (2x)^{m}e^{-t^{2}} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}2^{m}t^{2k + m}}{k!} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}H_{n}^{m}(0)\frac{t^{n}}{n!} \Rightarrow |n = 2k + m| \Rightarrow
$$
$$
H_{n}^{m}(0) = \frac{n!(-1)^{\frac{n - m}{2}}2^{m}}{\left( \frac{n - m}{2}\right)!}, \quad m \leqslant n ,
$$
and
$$
H_{n}^{m}(0) , \quad m \geqslant n.
$$
Then by returning to $(2)$ I got
$$
H_{n}(x) = \sum_{m = 0}^{n}\frac{n!(-1)^{\frac{n - m}{2}}2^{m}}{\left( \frac{n - m}{2}\right)!} \frac{t^{m}}{m!} = n! (-1)^{\frac{n}{2}}\sum_{m = 0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{-\frac{ m}{2}}2^{m}}{\left( \frac{n - m}{2}\right)!} \frac{t^{m}}{m!}.
$$
When $n = 2l$ sum $2k + m = 2l$ will be true only if $m = 2f$, and
$$
H_{2l}(x) = (2l)!(-1)^{l}\sum_{f = 0}^{l}\frac{2^{f}(-1)^{f}}{(l - f)!}\frac{x^{2f}}{f!}. 
$$ 
But I can't reduce it to hypergeometric function, because I have problem with $2^{f}$.

Where is the mistake?

Edit. It seems that I found it. I represented $(2f)!$ as $2^{f}f!$, which isn't correct.

The second edit. The question is closed. I represented $(2f)!$ as $(2f - 1)!! 2^{f}f!$, which then lead me to the answer.